# ContinueWith chaining not working as expected

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I have this example code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var t1 = Task.Run(async () => {
            Console.WriteLine("Putting in fake processing 1.");
            await Task.Delay(300);
            Console.WriteLine("Fake processing finished 1. ");
        });
        var t2 = t1.ContinueWith(async (c) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Putting in fake processing 2.");
            await Task.Delay(200);
            Console.WriteLine("Fake processing finished 2.");
        });
        var t3 = t2.ContinueWith(async (c)  => {
            Console.WriteLine("Putting in fake processing 3.");
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Console.WriteLine("Fake processing finished 3.");
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The console output baffles me:

- Putting in fake processing 1.
- Fake processing finished 1.
- Putting in fake processing 2.
- Putting in fake processing 3.
- Fake processing finished 3.
- Fake processing finished 2.

I am trying to chain the tasks so they execute one after another, what am I doing wrong? And I can't use await, this is just example code, in reality I am queueing incoming tasks (some asynchronous, some not) and want to execute them in the same order they came in but with no parallelism, ContinueWith seemed better than creating a ConcurrentQueue and handling everythning myself, but it just doesn't work...

Comment: the await statement "splits" the task. So t1 only references the first half. I am suprised Putting in fake processing 2 doesn't happen immediately after Putting in fake processing 1

Comment: @WeylandYutani I explain in my answer why that doesn't happen.

Comment: actually i am talking rubbish again so ignore me

Comment: @WeylandYutani It was wrong, but only because MS went out of their way to actively prevent that from happening.  As I said, were he using `StartNew` instead that *would* be the behavior seen.  It's at least a somewhat understandable mistake to make.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the type of `t2`.  It's a `Task<Task>`.  `t2` will be completed *when it finishes starting the task that does the actual work* not when that work actually finishes.

The smallest change to your code to get it to work would be to add an `unwrap` after both your second and third calls to `ContinueWith`, so that you get out the task that represents the completion of your work.

The more idiomatic solution would be to simply remove the `ContinueWith` calls entirely and just use `await` to add continuations to tasks.

Interestingly enough, you would see the same behavior for `t1` if you used `Task.Factory.StartNew`, but `Task.Run` is specifically designed to work with `async` lambdas and actually internally unwraps all `Action<Task>` delegates to return the result of the task returned, rather than a task that represents starting that task, which is why you don't need to unwrap that task.

Comment: Thank you, Unwrap works (can't use await since the real code is not a linear list, I am receiving a stream of tasks to execute serially, so they need to be queued. Of course I would love to use await instead :)).

Comment: @MartinSykora Yes, you *could* use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`, although it's hard to show you how without knowing the specifics of your situation.  Most likely you'd simply be able to write an `async` method that accepts a task, awaits it, along with awaiting other things and calling other methods, and then returning a `Task`.  Pretty much any time you're calling `ContinueWith` on a task you can probably call `await` on it instead and have it come out nicer, with only rare exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

> in reality I am queueing incoming tasks (some asynchronous, some not) and want to execute them in the same order they came in but with no parallelism

You probably want to use TPL Dataflow for that. Specifically, [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var block = new ActionBlock<object>(async item =>
{
  // Handle synchronous item
  var action = item as Action;
  if (action != null)
    action();

  // Handle asynchronous item
  var func = item as Func<Task>;
  if (func != null)
    await func();
});

// To queue a synchronous item
Action synchronous = () => Thread.Sleep(1000);
block.Post(synchronous);

// To queue an asynchronous item
Func<Task> asynchronous = async () => { await Task.Delay(1000); };
blockPost(asynchronous);
```

Comment: Nice, that might be just what I need if it works, definitely would be more elegant :-)